# Is this really Dynamic Polymorphism? What information is available to the compiler when we use a new opearator to instantiate a class?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

It us generally said that when we do  `Set<Stamp> stamps= new HashSet<Stamp>(); stamps.add(new Stamp());` it is an example of dynamic polymorphism . I find this confusing because when the code gets compiled the compiler knows ahead of time that `stamps` refers to an Object of type `HashSet<Stamp>` . So it knows how to deal with the add method during compile time only . How can this be an example of dynamic polymorphism?
         The basic difference between using the new operator and Class.forName().getInstance() is that in the former case the compiler knows the type of Class that we are trying to instantiate ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it only "knows" that `stamp` is a `Set`. It doesn't know that it is a `HashSet` after it is constructed.

Comment: But the actual class name is actually present in the byte code during compilation time only . So why do you say that it doesn't know that stamps refers to a HashSet<Stamp> instance ?

Comment: Imagine that `stamps` created by some magic method or injected by DI framework, so no information about concrete implementation

Answer (score 1):

Compiler knows that `stamps` is `Set<Stamp>` because you declared it so. It also knows that on one particular line you assign it to `new HashSet<Stamp>()`. Later you may reassign it to `new MyOwnSetImpl<Stamp>()` or anything that implements `Set<Stamp>`. You may have complex logic, that assigns `stamps` to one implementation of `Set<Stamps>` or another depending on user input. You can even debug your code, put a breakpoint before you call `.add()` and manually change `stamps` value to something that is not in your code during compilation. All these is perfectly valid. To allow you to do it, `.add()` is called dynamically - it will call `.add()` method of the class `stamps` is instance of, and it will find out what that class is in runtime.